# Connecting two shapes together, Silverlight 2

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, expression

I'm looking to connect or glue together two shapes or objects with a Line. These shapes will be generated dynamically, meaning I'll be calling a Web service on the backend to determine how many objects/shapes need to be created. Once this is determined, I'll need to have the objects/shapes connected together.

The method signature may look like this (similar to Visio's drawing capabilities):

```
GlueTogether(objButton1, objButton2);
```

I may need to get the position of each Rectangle shape or Button to determine where the starting Line point is. Then determine the second shape/objects position to draw the line.

Any help or suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Use a Path or a Line below the shapes in stacking order or z index
2. Use instance.TransformToVisual() to get the transform of each shape
3. Use the transform to transform the centerpoint of each shape
4. Draw a line between the two centerpoints.

---

```
var transform1 = shape1.TransformToVisual(shape1.Parent as UIElement);
var transform2 = shape2.TransformToVisual(shape2.Parent as UIElement);

var lineGeometry = new LineGeometry()
{
  StartPoint = transform1.Transform(new Point(shape1.ActualWidth / 2, shape1.ActualHeight / 2.0)),
  EndPoint = transform2.Transform(new Point(shape2.ActualWidth / 2.0,    shape2.ActualHeight / 2.0))
};

var path = new Path()
{
Data = lineGeometry
};
```

Comment: .FindCommonVisualAncestor Is handy if your shapes are nested in different places -- shape1.TransformToVisual(shape1.FindCommonVisualAncestor(shape2))

Answer (score 0):

I am trying much the same, but instead of the line going from one centre to the other I want the lines to stop at the edge of the two shapes.
In particular I have arrows at the end of the lines, and the arrows need to stop at the bounds of the shapes instead of going inside/behind the shape to its centre.

My shape is a usercontrol with a grid and rectangle, and some labels and other stuff.
I can't find any methods that provide me with a geometry for the edge of the shape (which is a rounded rectangle).

I figured out a solution that uses the bounding box and intersection points to connect my elements by lines at their approximate edges, and it works well for me using arrow ended lines.

See [Connecting two WPF canvas elements by a line, without using anchors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737509/connecting-two-wpf-canvas-elements-by-a-line-without-using-anchors/1737536#1737536)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://www.graphspe.com/Main.aspx#/Solution/graphviz-xaml-renderer

All you have to do is printf to a string and you get your Silverlight[2|3] diagram.

Ceyhun

Comment: Bad link - I get a "page under construction"

Answer (score 0):

In addition...  Instead of connecting to the center point of your objects, I've modified the same code from Michael S. to:

```
var lineGeometry = new LineGeometry()
{
    StartPoint = transform1.Transform(new Point(1 , b1.ActualHeight / 2.0)),
    EndPoint = transform2.Transform(new Point(b2.ActualWidth , b2.ActualHeight / 2.0))
};
```

This will connect at the outer portions of each object.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the above code to draw two buttons, I want a line between those two buttons, but all i get are two buttons that look like tiny circles and no line.

code:

```
Button b1 = new Button();
Button b2 = new Button();
canvas1.Children.Add(b1);
canvas1.Children.Add(b2);
Canvas.SetLeft(b1, 300);

var transform1 = b1.TransformToVisual(b1.Parent as UIElement);
var transform2 = b2.TransformToVisual(b2.Parent as UIElement);

var lineGeometry = new LineGeometry()
{
    StartPoint = transform1.Transform(new Point(1, b1.ActualHeight / 2.0)),
    EndPoint = transform2.Transform(new Point(b2.ActualWidth, b2.ActualHeight / 2.0))
};

var path = new Path()
{
    Data = lineGeometry
};

canvas1.Children.Add(path);
```