# Connecting two dynamically created shapes using line shape in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, shapes

Im working on flowchart kind of application in asp.net using silverlight.. Im a beginner in Silvelight, Creating the elements (Rectangle,Ellipse,Line.. ) dynamically using SHAPE and LINE Objects in codebehind (c#)

These shapes will be generated dynamically, meaning I'll be calling a Web service on the backend to determine how many objects/shapes need to be created. Once this is determined, I'll need to have the objects/shapes connected together.

how to connect dynamically created shapes with a line in Silverlight like a flowchart.

I read the below article, but its not working for me, actualHeight & actualWidth of shapes values are 0.
[Connecting two shapes together, Silverlight 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467951/connecting-two-shapes-together-silverlight-2)

here is my **MainPage.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="LightTest1.MainPage">

<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" Background="Red"></Canvas>
    <Button x:Name="btnPush" Content="AddRectangle" Height="20" Width="80" Margin="12,268,348,12" Click="btnPush_Click"></Button>               
</Canvas>
```

code behind **MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
    StackPanel sp1 = new StackPanel();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sp1.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        MyCanvas.Children.Add(sp1);
    }

    Rectangle rect1;
    Rectangle rect2;
    Line line1;

    private void btnPush_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rect1 = new Rectangle()
        {
            Height = 30,
            Width = 30,
            StrokeThickness = 3,
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
        };
        sp1.Children.Add(rect1);           

        rect2 = new Rectangle()
        {
            Height = 30,
            Width = 30,
            StrokeThickness = 3,
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
        };
        sp1.Children.Add(rect2);

        connectShapes(rect1, rect2);
    }

    private void connectShapes(Shape s1, Shape s2)
    {
        var transform1 = s1.TransformToVisual(s1.Parent as UIElement);
        var transform2 = s2.TransformToVisual(s2.Parent as UIElement);

        var lineGeometry = new LineGeometry()
          {
              StartPoint = transform1.Transform(new Point(1, s1.ActualHeight / 2.0)),
              EndPoint = transform2.Transform(new Point(s2.ActualWidth, s2.ActualHeight / 2.0))
          }; 

        var path = new Path()
        {
            Data = lineGeometry,
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green),
        };
        sp1.Children.Add(path);          
    }
```

what I am doing in button click event is just adding two rectangle shapes and tring to connect them with a line (like flowchart).
Please suggest what is wrong in my code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the line

```
    connectShapes(rect1, rect2);
```

with

```
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => connectShapes(rect1, rect2));
```

I'm not sure of the exact reason why this works, but I believe the shapes are only rendered once control passes out of your code, and only once they are rendered do the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties have a useful value.  Calling `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` calls your code a short time later; in fact, you may notice the lines being drawn slightly after the rectangles.

The `TransformToVisual` method behaves in much the same way as the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties.  It will return an identity transformation if the shape hasn't been rendered.  Even if your lines were being drawn with a definite width and height, they would end up being drawn all on top of one another at the top-left.

I also found that I needed to add the lines to the Canvas, not the StackPanel, in order for them to be drawn over the rectangles.  Otherwise the StackPanel quickly filled up with lines with a lot of space above them.